# How to Handle These types of Pop Up in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, java, selenium-webdriver, popup

[ScreenShot of Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MTrL.png).
I am unable to Handle these types of Javascript **Pop Ups** in **Selenium**. These Pop Ups Blocks the **click()** functionality.

```
def handle_popup(current_browser):
    try:
        # Attempt to handle an alert (dialog box) that might appear.
        alert = current_browser.switch_to.alert
        alert.dismiss()

    except NoAlertPresentException as e:
        try:
            for window_handle in current_browser.window_handles:
                current_browser.switch_to.window(window_handle)

                # Close the pop-up by simulating the 'Esc' key press.
                action = ActionChains(current_browser)
                action.send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)
                action.perform()

            # Close pop-up based on a specific element
            pop_up_element = re.findall(r'(?<=\<)(.*?)(?=\>)', str(e))[2]
            for element in current_browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '*'):
                try:
                    if pop_up_element in element.get_attribute('innerHTML'):
                        current_browser.execute_script("""var element = arguments[0]; 
                                    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);""", element)
                        logging.info(f"Closed pop-up with element: {pop_up_element}")
                        break
                except Exception as inner_exception:
                    logging.warning(f"Error handling pop-up element: {str(inner_exception)}")

        except Exception as outer_exception:
            logging.warning(f"No pop-up found or unable to handle: {str(outer_exception)}")

    finally:
        # Switch back to the original/default content.
        current_browser.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: that's not an alert.  Right-click on the close button and choose "Inspect" to find the element, and create a proper locator for it.  (or the div so you can send escape key if that closes it...)

Comment: I want to dynamically execute and manage this action on all websites within my test case that have this type of pop-up. Is there anything other technique that meets my requirements?